# How to automatically cancel periodic work (Workmanager)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I need to cancel/remove my work when it meets a condition. I`ve read that there is a method onStopped() that can be overridden, but it is for simple **:Worker** and not for **CoroutineWorker**.

**My worker:**

```
class MyJob(appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        val itemId = inputData.getLong("item_id",0)
        val itemDao = ItemDB.getInstance(applicationContext).itemDao()
        val itemRepository = ItemRepo(itemsDao)

        val item = itemRepository.getItemById(itemId)
        val newValue = item.a + item.b
        item.a = newValue
        itemRepository.updateItem(item)

        if(item.a == item.c){         
    WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).cancelUniqueWork("TEST_WORKER")
        }

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
My mistake, i forgot to mention that this is a unique periodic work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cancel the work by returning [`Result.failure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.Result#failure()); so you can add it under your condition

```
if(item.a == item.c){
    //Cancel work
    return Result.failure()
}
```

Now you need to listen to the work result in your activity/fragment; as you didn't provide this part of the code, I will do some assumptions, and listen to the work result with lifecycle observation model

```
// instantiate periodic work
final PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(...).build();

// schedule the work
WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(workRequest);

// observe the work
WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId())
        .observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WorkInfo workInfo) {
                if (workInfo.getState() == WorkInfo.State.FAILED) {
                    // cancelling work
                    WorkManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).cancelWorkById(workRequest.getId());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: but it will still be enqueued. It will be running, doing nothing but returning a failure.

Comment: so basically it means to constantly observer all workers and delete failed ones... I thought about it. But what if i just cancel the worker within itself? Is it a bad practice? Because i just tested and it works just fine. Check updated question...

Comment: @NickWilde .. the issue is that you need to cancel the worker and raise that within `doWork()`, I mean during executing your work, so you need to observe your work until that condition is met; and that is why I canceled it so;

Comment: @NickWilde there might be better solution, but  I didn't test it, you can have a listener that is implemented by your activity that initiates the periodic work, and pass an instance of that listener somehow to your Worker, and trigger its callback once you need to cancel your work and then use                     `WorkManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).cancelWorkById(workRequest.getId());` in activity's callback